# Is there a way to fire an event on the last select element in cofeescript

Tags: coffeescript, onchange

I work on a project which uses coffeescript, I have to generate a select element (combobox) dynamically, I generate it. But I want to fire an event on the last select element, but it doesn't work, I wrote like this.

```
 $("select:last").change ->
```

But it fires the event only when I change the first select element.

Comment: It gets compiled to javascript. Try writing raw javascript and see if it has the same behavior

Comment: I write the same example in jquery `$("select:last").on(chnage,function ` and it works, but I don't know why it doesn't work with coffeescript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `on` event?

```
$('select:last').on 'chnage', ->
```

Comment: yes I tried it but it doesn't work, actually there is no event fired on the dynamically created "select" even mouseover

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, you can do like this  `$(document.body).on 'change', 'select:last', ->`

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote looks correct.  Is the body of the method indented properly?  It should be one tab further to the right than the line you posted.

I would try making some of the syntax more explicit to rule out weird issues related to tabbing:

```
$("select:last").change{ () ->  }
```